# PHP image upload to Amazon s3 error: cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm uploading an image from `PHP` to **Amazon S3** servers.
It is stored successfully but I am not able to open the image ; I am getting this error:

> The image “https://s3.amazonaws.com/buckename/24aaffa670e634a7da9a087bfa83abe6_400x400.png” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

This is my code:

```
$sourcePath = $_FILES['filedata']['tmp_name'];

$actual_image_name='dinesh'.$_FILES['filedata']['name'];
$contentType= $_FILES['filedata']['type'];

S3::putObject($sourcePath,
              BUCKETNAME,
              baseName($actual_image_name),
              S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,array(),
              array('Content-Type' =>$contentType))
```

Comment: The xml clearly states that `NoSuchBucket` along with `The specified bucket does not exist`. Check the bucket you are uploading to and the one you are trying to get images out.

Comment: bucket name is correct i can see the image under the bucket. Issue is while open am getting error https://s3.amazonaws.com/healthbodyweb/dinesh24aaffa670e634a7da9a087bfa83abe6_400x400.png

Answer (score -1):

```
$value="SampleVideo1.mp4";
$disk = \Storage::disk('s3');
if ($disk->exists($value)) 
{
    $command = $disk->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient()->getCommand(
              'GetObject', [
                  'Bucket'  => \Config::get('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket'),
                   'Key'    => $value,
               ]);

    $request = $disk->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient()->createPresignedRequest($command, '+10 minutes');
    $generate_url = $request->getUri();
    echo $generate_url;
}
```